# Can WaitForSingleObject/WaitForMultipleObjects be used in an MTA thread?

Tags: multithreading, winapi, com

I apologize if the answer to this is obvious, but I'm still learning COM multithreading and just wanted to be sure.

The `WaitForSingleObject`/`WaitForMultipleObjects` [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject#remarks) state that those functions can't be used with `CoInitialize`, since the latter function indirectly creates a window.

But does that mean you can still use them with `CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)`?

And on a related note, can `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` and similar threadpool functions be used in an MTA?

Thanks for any info.

Comment: Note that there is `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(Ex)` which is a superset of `WaitForSingleObject` and `WaitForMultipleObjects` and *can* be used in an STA thread (because they process the message queue)

Comment: You can use all these functions if you know what you're doing (and use timeouts in waits), but it's better to follow the remarks. Note the doc clearly mentions CoInitialize, not CoInitializeEx, because MTA initialization doesn't create a window. STA uses a window to process message, hence all the warnings.

Comment: Yeah, the reason I'm asking is that I'd like to use ATL's `CWorkerThread` to handle a lot of the housekeeping, and it uses `WaitForMultipleObjects`.  So that's the only reason I'm doing this.  Otherwise I'd follow the remarks.

Comment: Using Windows' thread pool doesn't require lots of house keeping, if you don't really need to create thread.

Comment: @BenVoigt `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(Ex)` not process message queue, but signaled (internal event) when new messge added and `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(Ex)` return. after this we need call `PeekMessage`, which already really process message queue